# Vlookup in a column with condition

Tags: excel, vlookup

Hope you can help me with this. I would like to use the function VLOOKUP to search for a data in a column. And this is easy for me, but I would like that the vlookup would skip the cells of that column to search in where the adjacent cell in the adjacent column has a "x" value in it. How can I design it? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use a helper column.

Let's say you are VLOOKUP-ing on column B, and want to skip rows where column A has "x". 
Helper formula in column C: `=IF(A1<>"x",B1,"")`

Then do your lookup on column C rather than column B

Comment: Tx for your Help!!

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
=index(a:a, aggregate(15, 7, row($1:$9999)/((a$1:a$9999="my value")*(b$1:b$9999<>"x")), 1))
```

Comment: Tx for your help!!